# Sub menu in html

Tags: html, css

I am creating a Sub menu on my menu. It is showing the names in the menu and I have then got the names I want in the sub menu showing on the menu which I only want when a cursor is hovering over the menu. Thanks

**CSS:**

```
#nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
    transition: .3s background-color;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1;
    padding: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
}
#nav a {
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>    <a href="Index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=".php">Who are we</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href=".php">Sports </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=".php">Football</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Rugby</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Hockey</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Golf</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Tennis</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="health.php">Health</a></li>
    <li><a href=".php">Nutrition</a></li>
    <li><a href="personaltrainers.php">Personal Trainers</a></li>
    <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
      <li><a href=".php">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href=".php">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What, *exactly*, is your question?

Comment: To allow the menu to not show "football, rugby" but at the moment it shows at the moment even when you don't click on the menu.

Comment: look this example, do you want this? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h740e1yv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your stuff classes.  You should also get rid of your float left on `#nav li` and instead give them `display: inline-block;`  Then give your child `ul` a `display: none;`, `position: absolute;` and `padding: 0;`  Have the `display: block` activate on hover of the parent `li`.  You can give the `li`'s `display: block;` to make them sit on top of each other.  See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmulder5/usf8szhu/2/)

```
<li class="sport-wrapper">
    <a href=".php">Sports </
    <ul class="sports">
     <li><a href=".php">Football</a></li>
     <li><a href=".php">Rugby</a></li>
     <li><a href=".php">Hockey</a></li>
     <li><a href=".php">Golf</a></li>
     <li><a href=".php">Tennis</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>



.sports {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.sport-wrapper:hover .sports {
    display: block;
}



 #nav .sports li {
    display: block;
 }
 #nav li {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jordanmulder

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```css
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav ul.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    background-color: red;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #333;
}

#nav a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}

#nav > ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=".php">Who are we</a></li>
    <li><a href=".php">Sports</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href=".php">Football</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Rugby</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Hockey</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Golf</a></li>
        <li><a href=".php">Tennis</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="health.php">Health</a></li>
    <li><a href=".php">Nutrition</a></li>
    <li><a href="personaltrainers.php">Personal Trainers</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @smdsgn